# Escape hashtag sign in shell for git alias

Tags: shell, hashtag

I have a git alias i use, here:

```
[alias]
    wrapup = "!f() { number=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | tr -dc '0-9'); git add . && git commit -m "\"Close #$number"\"; }; f"
```

I need to escape the `#` sign.

How should i do that, i've tried to escape it with three \\\ but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing the line *by git*, the `"` are parsed in pairs:

```
wrapup = "!f().... in double quotes "\" not in double quotes # this is a comment "\" in double quotes "
```

The `#` character when not inside double quotes is just a comment, as anywhere else.

You have to escape `"` when inside `"`:

```
wrapup = "!f() { number=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | tr -dc '0-9'); git add . && git commit -m \"Close #$number\"; }; f"
```